# Some applications' tray icon images disappearing after screensaver and stand-by

Tags: unity, 16.10, system-tray

On my two laptops running Ubuntu 16.10, each time they go to sleep, or after the screensaver (i.e. Ubuntu's default screen turn off), some tray icons are missing their images. I mean, the placeholder is there, but the image is missing. I'm attaching an image:

[image: Team Viewer missing icon after stand-by]

For reference, here's how it should look like:

[image: Team Viewer icon after stand-by]

This far I've noticed the problem exists only with Skype Alpha and Team Viewer icons, whereas all others seem to work fine.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using Arc GTK theme with Faenza icon theme.

What ever could be causing this?

Comment: the same for chrome